# No results on MySql Select after an Update using a MySqlDataAdapter with a MySqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have the following code that is meant to simply test and try to resolve an issue I'm having where MySQL appears to return no results immediately when attempting to select a record after another record has just been updated.  I've tried creating all new objects without using a loop just to make sure something wasn't still in scope.  I've tried adding Thread.Sleep(3000) between loop iterations to see if that would help.  So far it's been consistent, the first select and update commands are successful, and the next select fails immediately.

**If, however, I remove the update, the Select works on the second iteration.**

```
for (int orderId = 1; orderId <= 2; orderId++)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM tblOrder WHERE orderId = " + orderId;
    var conn = GetConnection(); //Returns a new connection instance
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    var cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);

    var orderDataTable = new DataTable();                    

    da.Fill(orderDataTable);

    if (orderDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("Order ID [" + orderId + "] not found.");

    Console.Write("Order ID [ " + orderId + "] was found...");

    orderDataTable.Rows[0]["notes"] = orderDataTable.Rows[0]["notes"].ToString() + " ";

    da.Update(orderDataTable);
    Console.Write("Update Test Passed\r\n");

}
```

GetConnection looks like this...

```
private const string ConnectionString = "myConnectionString";

public static MySqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    return new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
}
```

Should go without saying, but I've definitely checked to make sure the orderId I'm selecting is there.

I believe the issue has something to do with MySql locking mechanisms, but I'm more of a SQL Server guy so I'm not terribly familiar with the peculiarities of MySql.  I tried changing the SELECT to end with "FOR UPDATE" and that did not seem to help.

**Update: Writing my own update statement and using a separate MySqlCommand object works, but is not preferred since my actual code updates a lot of fields and logic and I would prefer not to have to form the update statement within that logic.**

Comment: Any reason you are getting new connections - can you get the connection outside of the loop.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `MySqlCommandBuilder` and never using it?

Comment: Instantiating the MySqlCommandBuilder against the MySqlDataAdapter creates the update statement automatically and enables the da.Update() to work.

Comment: @PaulF I wanted to make sure the problem was not related to reuse of the connection.  Originally my code had the connection being defined outside the loop iteration, and once I identify the problem I'll return it to that assuming it's not related (which I doubt at this point).

Comment: I guess I debug like that too. Why do you think it is a timeout problem? Have you got logging enabled on MySQL server?

Comment: @PaulF What actually happens is that no rows are returned (even though the record definitely exists).  At one point I was debugging and drilled down into one of the objects and saw that MySql had actually returned a timeout message.  I'll try to do that again and post a more specific answer to that question.  But see my most recent update.  I don't believe it's actually a timeout, I think it has to do with record locking.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out where I saw a reference to a timeout.  I am going to remove the timeout language from the question, as it is probably misleading.

Comment: Have you looked at the UpdateCommand that is generated by the command bulder?

Comment: In the MSDN example there is a call to GetBuilderCommand before doing the update - have you tried that? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx

Comment: Just tried it, same result, but I think you're onto something.  I created my own update command and used a separate MySqlCommand object to do the update and the test passed.  I just really didn't want to have to code the update command since the production code updates a large number of fields.  But if I have to, I could use that as a workaround.